# hive Permission denied while executing select command

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have login as testuser and enter into hive shell.
While executing select  * query for hive I am getting following error:

```
> select * from itable1;
>     OK
>     Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException:
> Permission denied: user=testuser, access=EXECUTE,
> inode="/user/hive/warehouse":hive:hive:drwxrwx--T
```

Can anybody help me to resolve the error?

Comment: Please format the exception text as it is pretty hard to read. Apart from that, I would guess that "testuser" simply does not have proper permissions - I fear that from there on your question is too vague and will not get many answers.

Answer (score 1):

try this : `sudo chmod -R og+rx /usr/local/hive/metadata`

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have  execute permission on the file. if no then change the permission of file using chmod command

chmod 755 file_path ( warehouse dir incase of internal table)

if external table change the file permission to which external table is pointed

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive/warehouse
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.